# Why does not safari translation work?

Tags: safari, google-chrome

I notice [safari 17 has translation](https://www.apple.com/safari/) but I can't make it work.

I have turned it on, but it does not work and it doesn't seem to work at all, compared to the Chrome translation plugin, once you turn it on you can see it immediately tries to translate and then gives you the final result.

[image: safari translation]

Compared to Chrome translation plugin,

[image: chrome translation]